# Cannot find Init! encrypted lvm root partition

Tags: linux, lvm, luks

Today I decided to move my root partition to an encrypted luks partition with lvm, but ran into some trouble.
This was my initial setup

```
-- sda
    - sda1 (debian)
    - sda2 (secondary)
    - sda5 (swap)
    - sda6 (home)  
    - sda7 (voidlinux)
```

I split up sda1 into a 512M boot partition(sda1) and the rest I'd use for voidlinux(sda3). It became

```
-- sda
    - sda1 (boot)
    - sda2 (secondary)
    - sda5 (swap)
    - sda6 (home)
    - sda7 (void)
    - sda3 (for void)
```

I then encrypted sda3,created an lvm vg named 'vg', created the lv 'root'.

```
-- sda
    - sda1 (boot)
    - sda2 (secondary)
    - sda5 (swap)
    - sda6 (home)
    - sda7 (void)
    - sda3
       - enc
          - vg-root
```

Created an ext4 filesystem on `/dev/vg/root`, mounted it then unpacked the backup tar archive I created prior, into it. The tar archive contained `/boot` `/usr` `/etc` and `/var` from my void `/`.

Mounted `/dev/vg/root` at `/mnt`, created directories `/mnt/{proc,dev,sys,tmp}` then ran `for i in proc dev sys tmp ;do mount --rbind /$i /mnt/$i ;done`.

Ran `mv /mnt/boot/*6.1* /mnt/tmp` then `mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/boot` and finally `mv /mnt/tmp/*6.1* /mnt/boot`.

Created these symlinks under `/mnt`, `[bin->/usr/bin, lib->/usr/lib, lib32->/usr/lib32, lib64->/usr/lib, sbin->/usr/bin]`. Then chrooted into `/mnt`.

I tried running a couple of programs, everything worked ok. Next I edited `/etc/default/grub`, `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="loglevel=4 rd.auto cryptdevice=/dev/sda3:enc"`.
Installed grub `grub-install /dev/sda`. grub.cfg `grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg`.
Rebuilt initramfs with `dracut -f`
Added the entry `/dev/vg/root / ext4 defaults 0 1` and `/dev/sda1 /boot ext2 defaults 0 0` to `/etc/fstab`.

When I rebooted I entered my passphrase then I got this... `Cannot find init! Please check to make sure you passed a valid root filesystem!`
I'm stuck here and can't figure out what to do next, help me out please.
This is the full log I got from dracut rescue shell. [pastebin](https://rentry.co/9yeoeg)

Answer (score 1):

Solved it. The symlinks [bin,lib*,sbin] should have been relative, i.e bin->usr/bin... [This](https://github.com/dracutdevs/dracut/issues/504) fragment of code within the shell script `init` within the `initramfs` helped me figure it out.